# How is the MIT licence not viral and how to practically comply with it?

Tags: licensing, mit-license

I've read online that MIT is a permissive licence which allows for the code to be used in propriety products, but the licence texts seems to conflict with that, which I'll quote below:

> Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
> a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
> "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
> without limitation the rights to use, **copy,** modify, merge, publish,
> distribute, sublicense, and/or **sell copies of the Software,** and to
> permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
> the following conditions:
>
> **The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.**
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
> EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
> MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
> CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
> TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
> SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

So, it seems according to the licence, derivative works must distribute the licence, and hence give those who receive the software the right to re-distribute the software, which is incompatible with most commercial software licences.

A strict reading would be that only **exact** copies have to distribute the copyright notice, although this seems a bit silly, as it is trivial to perform a minor modification to avoid an exact copy. Why would the licence bother including the restriction to maintain the copyright notice when that restriction is so easily circumvented?

So if "copy" includes derived works, I can only conclude that any work derived from a MIT licenced work must permit free redistribution, which means it's not really a commercial friendly licence.

The only way around this seems to include the MIT licence files, but then say that these licence files only apply to certain parts to the software, oh and by the way the rights you get to redistribute those parts doesn't really apply practically because they're part of the compiled code now and tightly coupled with bits you can't redistribute (particularly if it wasn't a separate library but just some source code copied into the commercial project).

That seems crazy, and I've also never seen such a notice. But on the other hand, just distributing the MIT licence with the software without these qualifications seems to me that a court might reasonable rule that it applies to the whole software, as you can't break compiled code into one executable into "parts" in any sense.

I'd note also, that if I'm using software `X`, which contains code from `X1`, `X2`, `X3` ... `XN`, to use software `X` myself presumably I'd have to include the licences from `X1`, `X2`, `X3` ... `XN` in distributions of my software.

So for every open source library I use, I'd have to look into its dependencies, find all the licences for it's dependencies, then look into those dependencies, and find all the licences for them, and so on.

This seems like an absolute nightmare, not really "permissive" as the `MIT` licence is commonly described. It seems completely impractical to comply with.

Am I correct in this analysis or have I totally missed something?

Comment: Clearly, if you want to modify something, you have to copy it first. My IANAL opinion is that you have to include the license even in modified copies.

Comment: Since this question is about understanding and complying with open source licenses, you might want to ask it on [opensource.se] instead (and delete it here). The question does not seem to be about software engineering as defined in the [help/on-topic]. Resurrecting and drastically expanding a year-old question is also rather weird, surely it would be better to ask a new but more focused question?

Comment: "So if "copy" includes derived works" It doesn't. The MIT license only talks about the software you received under that license.

Answer (score 11):

Software licenses only apply to the part of the software that the licensor owns copyright.

If you use MIT-licensed software as a part of a larger work (e.g. as a library or module), only that component is required to be covered by the MIT license. The code you write can be licensed however you choose.

This is how, for example, Microsoft was able to sell Windows NT despite containing some BSD-licensed open-source code.

If you are unsure how to integrate software covered by the license into your own product from a licensing perspective, you will need to consult with an intellectual property attorney to ensure that your specific software project is set up correctly from a legal perspective. Here on Software Engineering we are able to speak to the broad ideas of copyright and licensing, but are not qualified to dig into the details of your particular situation nor can we dispense legal advice.

Answer (score 4):

## How is the MIT licence not viral?

Because using code licensed by the MIT License does not require your whole application to be released under the MIT License.  Period.  In other words, the code that you write yourself is yours.  It's copyrighted and licensed by you (you get to choose which license you prefer to use).  **The portion of code you did not write is *still* the copyrighted property of the original author** (see below for when the author is an organization).  You are still required to display the copyright notice and license from the MIT licensed code. However, you could release your code under a creative commons license or keep it proprietary.

Whether you use the MIT Licensed code as a library or you actually take the code and incorporate it into your product, the only code that is MIT Licensed is the code that came from that source.

This is in stark contrast to the GPL license.  If you were to do the same with GPL code, you would be required to distribute your project under the GPL license--making it viral.  That was done intentionally by it's creator, Richard Stallman.

*NOTE: there are legal disputes regarding linking to a GPL library from a non-GPL project and whether that requires your project to be GPL.  To my knowledge the GPL has not been formally tested in court so there is no precedence to work from.  It is also unknown how the GPL is treated in legal systems arount the world.*

## How to comply with it?

That's actually pretty easy.

1. Don't change the copyright notice in any files from the MIT licensed project
2. If there is an attribution clause (some variations do) then your application needs to say that it uses code from the MIT licensed project

## What can I do with MIT licensed code?

Like the license says you can do any and all of the following:

- copy
- modify
- merge
- publish
- distribute
- sub-license
- sell copies

Practically that means you can fork any MIT licensed code, make changes, and redistribute your forked copy as you see fit.  It means you can take one or two files/functions from the MIT licensed project and incorporate it in your code.  It means there are no restrictions from you selling your software simply because you forked some MIT licensed code and incorporated it in your own project.

## What can I NOT do with MIT licensed code?

1. Claim copyright.  You didn't write it, and the copyright notice must remain in tact for the MIT licensed code.  Period.
2. Have protection from code that implements patents.  ASL 2.0 was modified to specifically address those concerns and none of the clauses needed to convey patent license(s) with the software license.

### More information on copyright

Copyright is a very complex subject, and is slightly different depending on what nation you are in.  However, there are some general principles that do apply to countries that have copyright laws:

- If you wrote it, you hold the *implicit* copyright
- Registering a copyright is not necessary, but helps end disputes quicker if you ever have to go to court
- As a copyright owner, you can *license* other people to use your copyrighted material.  That license provides the limits of the freedoms people can take with your copyrighted code
- It is unlawful to claim copyright for any work that you did not create.

Rules diverge a little bit on corporate copyright ownership, etc. depending on your locale.  Most large open source projects (like Apache, who is governed by US copyright law) retain a corporate copyright to the source code, and requires all contributors to sign an agreement that all work on Apache Software is a "work for hire" so the copyright belongs to the Apache Software Foundation.  Within US Copyright law, this is both correct and lawful.

If you don't understand copyright law, particularly for where you are from, then I highly recommend you take a class or two to at least cover the basics.  Even a short seminar can shed a lot of light.

A *license* cannot grant the copyright to anyone.  The law for transferring ownership of a copyright varies from country to country.  In the USA, copyright is treated like real estate, so it can be bought and sold like a house.  In other countries, you might not be able to transfer ownership at all.

Comment: I think this is a very optimistic reading of the licence. Clearly if I do a minor modification, say change tabs to spaces, rebuild and distribute the binary, I have no copyright claims and the MIT licence requires me to distribute my version under the MIT licence

Comment: @Ewan, No license transfers copyright.  That is a different matter altogether.  You merely have the **license** to redistribute your version of the code.  I repeat, copyright remains with the original authors.  Transferring copyright through sale or other means is subject to the laws of the country in which the copyright is held.  **NEVER** assume a license gives you the copyright.

Comment: That is exactly the assumption you are making.

Comment: @Ewan, how?  I did not say you can claim the library is yours.  I did not say you could change the copyright banner.  Both of those are restrictions in the license.  I will make some updates to the answer to make that clearer.  It'll be later this afternoon since something literally came up while typing this response.

Comment: You are claiming that you have copyright over the stuff you write. "Period." this just isn't true, for example the tabs to spaces.

Comment: Even if you add a larger change, say i add a new method to a library class. Its not at all clear that I would not be required to distribute the new version (with my copyrighted bits) under the MIT licence

Comment: @Ewan, at no point before my edits did I even mention the word copyright.  I clarified what I meant, and I added a section on the license does not provide.  Hopefully this makes it much clearer.  I can't think of any way other than recommending you consult a lawyer to make it clearer.

Comment: its clear, but wrong.

Comment: @Ewan The MIT license doesn't say a word about the code you write. It is only about the code you obtained from someone else under that license.

Comment: ben, you are simply wrong about copyright law. you don't own the copyright on your changes unless you have made a significant creative input of your own. That makes it a derivative work rather than a straight up copy. And even then you cant publish that derivative work without a licence. The condition of which in this case is that you publish the work under the MIT licence. If I just change the spaces, its a straight up copy, I def cant change the licence. If I add a method then I can argue that its a derivative work and I own the copyright on the new method. But I still cant distribute it...

Comment: ... without a licence for the origional work. since the new method is inseperable I would be physically unable to publish one method under one licence and the rest under the other.

Comment: tue only edge case is where you distribute the orgional work as a plug in. then you can _argue_ that its a separate thing. But even here whether it is or not is up to the courts, I could sue you, claim that your program is equivilant to a new method and must be distributed under MIT under the terms of my licence and potentially win

Comment: also. you are wrong about patents as well. The MIT licence uses terminology from US patent law and thus its unclear as to whether patent rights are granted or not

Comment: @Ewan, I feel further discussion will not be constructive.  It's clear we have differing opinions on what I believe I wrote and what you believe I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the MIT license is called permissive because it has very few requirements that must be fulfilled to satisfy the license when creating a derived work. In fact, the only requirement is that you don't remove the copyright, permission notice and disclaimer.

Also, copyright law does not presume that if a part of a larger work is under license X, then all of that work is expected to be licensed the same way. The default assumption in copyright law is that a copyright license only applies to whatever is placed explicitly under that license.

- A license notice at the top (or bottom) of a source file applies only to the contents of that file
- A license notice at a common location in a project applies only to the files of that project

In fact, the GPL uses some specially crafted text to try to apply to more than just the files explicitly brought under the GPL and it has not yet been proven in court that this holds up to scrutiny.

On a different note, the MIT license grants you the right to **sublicense** the work.

All this combined makes that you can take a MIT-licensed library, combine it with your own (commercial) code and offer the resulting binary only under your own closed-source license.
The requirement in the MIT license is that you can't remove the license notice, but not that you have to reproduce it in a different location if you distribute binaries only.

---

Regarding having to check all recursive dependencies for their licenses, that is something you have to do anyway to know what each part requires of you in order to be allowed to re-use it. And you should also do it to make sure that the dependency tree does not contain anything that is under the GPL or a similar strong copyleft license.
In the end, you are legally responsible for complying with all the licenses of third-party contents of your work.

Comment: If you use the MIT-licensed source code plus a bit if your source code to compile a binary, and distribute that binary without the MIT notice, haven't you effectively removed the notice?

Comment: @nog642, I suggest you ask that in a new question (if one doesn't already exist).

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear.

The problem is that a "Derivative Work" can legally (depending on jurisdiction) be something which requires the MIT licensed software to function.

You can't make a Derivative Work without respecting the licence conditions and "the Software" is not defined in the licence.

Without a clear permission to make Derivative Works, and licence them differently, in the licence you are left with hacky solutions like distributing the MIT licensed dll as a separate download and *arguing* that that means your program isn't a Derivative Work.

We will only know the true situation after a number of people have been taken to court and established a legal precedent one way or the other.

However, we should note that if you are in the position to worry about being sued by the provider of free software. Then by far the best solution regardless of the exact licence is simply to contact the copyright owner and purchase from them a commercial licence with your required wording

Comment: I'm not sure in which jurisdiction the content of my favorite music CD might be considered "derivative work" of my CD player...even for (L)GPL licenses the "derivative work" is a very opinionated and debatable point (not in the _spirit_ but legally).

Comment: its worldwide now http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_IP-03-1152_en.htm

Comment: No, note that I wrote _"...the **content** of my favorite CD..."_. Technology to both build the media and then to declare it as _compatible_ and label it as "CD" is **patented** (which is a pretty different thing). The content of the CD (the music) needs the media (CD) which needs the player (CD player) but it cannot, under any circumstance, be considered "derivative work". I think the best definition of d.i. I know/I'm aware of is in the US copyright law.

Comment: well the content without a cd obviously doesnt require a cd player. as soon as you start making cds with the content on you need a licence of some kind. its definitely a derivitive work of a cd, no question. the cd is probably a derivitive work of the cd player, but its a chicken and egg situation. I guess the spec is the origional work

Comment: Hmmmm IANAL but CD isn't _derivative work_, simply you can't produce them without some **patented** technologies (and maybe, I'm not sure) you can't label it as "CD" without permission because it's a trademark (or whatever). Definition of derivative work doesn't include "use"...that's exactly the point GPL license is so tricky in its wording (to the point to _pretend_ to be a _contract_ instead of a license).

Comment: sorry I think you are wrong about cds. but its not a great analogy. The point is its the legal question of whether your software is or is not a derivative work which is key and the licence dosent explicity address those rights

Comment: OK, it's pointless to discuss about CDs but what constituite "derivate work" is exactly the core of the question and license cannot enforce it against what LAW says about it. Imagine that an hypotetical license says that if you use their software (let's say...Ms Word) then 10% of your revenue must be used to clean the ocean from plastic.

Comment: Now please follow me: that's not a simple license...it's a CONTRACT (or maybe an agreement) but distinction is incredibly important. GPL wording (for example) tries to estabilish a contract ("derivative work is everything that uses this..."), that's why it's so [legally] controversial and there is a huge grade of uncertainity when it has to be enforced in a court.

Comment: ok. im imagining

Comment: With a license I, essentially, give you my permission to use my property. A contract, however, comes with mutual obligations (and most sw licenses explicitely exclude any obligation from the provider...)

Comment: sure, but I only grant you a licence if you accept and abide by the terms of the 'license agreement' which is a contract.

Comment: But as you said that is an **agreement** which grants you a license. An agreement is a contract. That's exactly the point: OSF states that GPL is NOT a contract (even if this distinction is modern and artificial) because contract law widely (and wildly) varies by country and often (but not always) is not unilateral while a license is.

Comment: However if it's not a contract then it has more restrictions on what it can say/ask (it's merely "take it, I grant you the right to use it but I retain the _copyright_"). Why this? Because in most countries a contract, to be valid and binding, must be both reciprocal and there must be a payment. With this we're to the point: GPL is a license (in the sense it's unilateral and grants the rights to use it in respect to copyright laws) but it has binding clauses like a contract (which can't be enforced in every country because it's free and not explicitely reciprocal...)

Comment: well that's where the jurisdiction comes in AND the need for actual legal precedents. Frankly though in practice we 'agree' to a licence agreements with no payment or mutual obligation all the time. Yes you might have trouble getting that 10% of revenue if the licensee simply refused to abide by the imaginary terms, but you would have a strong case of copyright breach, if they continued to use your software after you tell them to stop.

Comment: That's completely true, "what will happen if" is completely unclear (and I guess it'll be more about the _power_ of parties than anything else...). I don't exactly remember GPL wording but if it's _invalid_ then, in some jurisdictions, the whole text may be considered invalid (that's why some licenses state that if one part is null the everything else is still valid). What will happen in that case? No one knows...

Comment: Hence my last paragraph "if you are in the position to worry..." The question is about about how to follow the conditions of the agreement, not the consequences of not following it.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, my comment(s) came from the "derivative work" thing. It's an extremely controversial and unclear legal matter. Think about Visual Studio (commercial, closed source) which includes a binding to Git (and possibly git client even if automatically separately downloaded). Should it be considered d.i.? No. Is it legal? Probably yes, in most jurisdictions and because no one will take MS to a court for this. Where is the line between "use" and "derivative work"? Depends on jurisdiction, licenses can retain only copyright (if they can't be considered contracts)

Comment: Sometimes I'm pretty happy to be a programmer and not a lawyer...

Comment: the git client in VS is a good example of the hacky approach. MS does everything it can to leave the door open to either VS being completely separate from git or a derivative work where the licence only applies to the plugin, not VS. Even then they have a huge EULA covering their arses

Comment: True, they _insulate_ VS behind a plugin. I'm sure it's legally correct (for sure according to US copyright law) but completely outside GPL license spirit (I think...otherwise any thin wrapper around some GPL may well _insulate_ it and stop the _viral_ propagation of GPL itself...)